# Top property is not honored in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to keep the top row moving like we move the first column in a table using jQuery?

The code I used to keep the first column moving during scroll is something like this.

```
$('#table-name').scroll(function () {
        var _left = $(this).scrollLeft();
        $('.firstTd').css('left', _left);

});
```

when I use the same technique to top property to a table row...through the CSS gets applied it is not honored by the browsers.

P.S: I used left property on **td** element and want to apply the same technique to a **tr** tag

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/8w4qac30/7/

Comment: The positioning of table elements is a law unto itself and cannot be easily affected by absolute positioning rules. If you can give a sample of your HTML and a description of what you want to achieve there may be a work around

Comment: i have added the demo ... do check

Comment: There is no `.test` element in your fiddle

Comment: @Mr.Noob updated answer

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Want i want is a fixed row during vertical scroll

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález thanks ...works when i use top instead of left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Oops, understood the question bad. I'll keep the info below, but actually my answer is this.

As `tr`s are quite picky, the only thing I can think of is to select all the `td`s and move them, like you do with the first one, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8w4qac30/9/

*Old answer*

`left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` are positioning attributes, and for them to work you should set the `position` attribute too.

`position` attributes come in different flavors:

- `relative` means to position the element relative to itself, so if you add, for example, `left: 20px` to a relative positioned element, it simply will shift its position 20 pixels to the left.
- `absolute` means to position the element relative to the first parent that is also `relative` or `absolute` positioned.
- `fixed` means to position the element relative to the browser window and will keep fixed during scrolls without additional code. I think that you should go this way.

Check this:
[image]

Check the positions here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: How can i fix the top few rows like i have fixed the first column as shown in demo

Comment: This is a handy guide, but not relevant to the OPs problem at all

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh, don't saw the demo link... I thought that is was the typical thing that a `fixed` position solves :-/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but want i want is fixed row during vertical scroll

Comment: @Mr.Noob Edited. Just have to change left for top.

Comment: @Mr.Noob Oh, I saw you already did it in your other comment. Nice. Would you mind to accept if this fits your needings?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Whenever the table is scrolled, the moved data is somewhat visible behind the fixed content. Is there any workaround to completly hide it?

Comment: @Mr.Noob That's because the tds have a transparent background. Just change it via the css `background` property (usually `background-color`)